# Reocurring error! the server quit without updating pid file

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, mysql, apache-2.4

Dedciated Server Linux Cenos 6 Apache + Nginx

We have had this issue happen several times now and happening after server has crashed or shut down

the server quit without updating pid file

After this MySQL does not start keep giving this error
the server quit without updating pid file

In the past the only way for mysql to get started again was to remove all files including ibdata1 from ver/lib/mysql  - resulting in us having to reimport all databases from backup again.

This error happened again today - after the server closed down and restarted itself twice ovenight.

However on this occasion I have been able to start MYSQL after adding this line in etc/my.cnf

innodb_force_recovery = 4

Please can someone help me understand why we are keep getting this issue and how to prevent it from happening in the future - I have read in past that enabling oomkill prevents this issue from happening in case of server failure or any other reason but we have had the same issue happening several times since then

The error.log was massive so copying some lines from before the issue 16 and 18 Aug and some from after the error - and also some from after innodb_force_recovery = 4 was added to etc/my.cnf   since then the log file has not been updated -

2020-08-16 22:08:34 8142 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table jawi_6jun20/core_cache_option from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2020-08-16 22:08:34 8142 [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'admin_rule-bkp-5-aug-2020'

2020-08-18 00:30:57 2ab9cb842700 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "htfr_07aug2020"."customer_address_entity_text" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2020-08-18 00:30:57 8142 [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'admin_rule-bkp-5-aug-2020'

2020-08-24 00:01:10 2ad344040700 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "htfr_07aug2020"."quote" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2020-08-24 00:01:13 2ad344040700 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.

020-08-24 14:08:21 13903 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery was set to 4. Continuing crash recovery even though we cannot access the .ibd file of this table.
2020-08-24 14:08:21 13903 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2020-08-24 14:08:21 13903 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 40054719901
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 1 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 1124333568
2020-08-24 14:08:22 13903 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.47 started; log sequence number 40054719901
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 4 !!!
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-08-24 14:08:23 13903 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.47'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Show the relevant `mysqld.log` and `/var/log/messages` lines.

Comment: That's unreadable. You should edit your question, not paste into temporary comments.

Comment: i tried removing etc/my.cnf  innodb_force_recovery = 4 after mysql restarted but it does not stop or restarting if i remove that line

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00DKNehq2wGin6ab82kIsrz5lhQjw%3A1598293482637&ei=6gVEX628JsHE0PEPlcmL6A4&q=site%3Adba.stackexchange.com+mysql+quit+without+updating+pid+file&oq=site%3Adba.stackexchange.com+mysql+quit+without+updating+pid+file&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCAAQRxCwA1DTFVjSGWC_JGgBcAB4AIAB6QGIAdIEkgEFMi4wLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwit2Z2au7TrAhVBIjQIHZXkAu0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5

Comment: what about google rick?

Comment: Check the links in that search.  Also, did you move some files around manually?

Comment: only deleted old databases via Cpanel but this issue keeps happening even before without making any changes whatsoever - im more interested in what is causing it so i can avoid in future -

Comment: @jt9489        What is the TEXT result of SELECT @@VERSION;  ?